# Access violation at address XXXX in module 'winspool.drv'. Read of address XXXX

Tags: windows-server-2012, print-server

I am running a c# application that shells out to a PDF printer and prints documents (roughly a document every second, to different printers).  I randomly get these errors being returned from the spooler, but on retry (automatically) within a second or two, it works perfectly.  We have had some problematic printer drivers that have been removed, and the rest are relatively solid well known and mature drivers.

Can anyone offer any advice or starting points to try and resolve it.  It appears / happens on two separate guest virtual servers, with only a single print server in question.

Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: Please update the PDF drivers on the printserver and let us know if the error persist

Comment: @yagmoth555 Could you explain why you think the PDF Printer drivers will cause an error in the spooler and if you mean PDF drivers (adobe) or PDF printer - not sure what you mean?

Comment: I mean the printer object its printing to, acrobat or anything else. The spooler will most of time fail because of a bad driver. Check on your print server if you can set the driver to isolated. It will only crash printqueue using that driver.

Comment: It is happening randomly.  More often than not 99.99% of the time, when I automatically retry (to the same printer), it prints successfully.  (I know I say randomly - I know there must be a pattern of sorts, but I don't see it).  Prints 1000's a day with a few giving an error.